# Calling a WCF method from a WPF client does nothing

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a very simple WCF service running that has a single method that returns an enum based on the result of the method.

I have tested this WCF service through a very simple console app both locally and over the internet to my server and both work perfectly fine. However once I use the, literally exact, code in my WPF application calling the method does nothing. No exception, no timeout. Testing it locally with a breakpoint at the start of the WCF method I found it does not even reach that far when calling it from WPF.

Both service reference configurations that were generated in the app.config are identical between the console and WPF application.

Edit: Had hoped to not need to put as much code in here but I'll just dump the whole thing.

In WPF the code is being called from a button in a dialog. This button triggers an Coroutine call using Caliburn.Micro. The WCF call is then being called in the Execute method from the Coroutine.

```
public IEnumerator<IResult> SendReport()
{
    var result = new Coroutines.SubmitNewExceptionIssueResult(Exception, UserNotes, Character);
    yield return result;
    if (result.Result == ErrorReportResult.OK)
        TryClose();
    else
        // TODO
}

public class SubmitNewExceptionIssueResult : IResult
{
    public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed;
    private ErrorReporterClient _client = new ErrorReporterClient();

    private Exception _exception { get; set; }
    private string _userNotes { get; set; }
    private Character _character { get; set; }
    public ErrorReportResult Result { get; private set; }

    public SubmitNewExceptionIssueResult(Exception ex, string userNotes, Character character)
    {
        _exception = ex;
        _userNotes = userNotes;
        _character = character;
    }

    public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        Result = _client.SendErrorReport(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_exception, new JsonSerializerSettings
                                         {
                                             TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                                         }),
                                         _userNotes,
                                         JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_character, new JsonSerializerSettings
                                         {
                                             TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                                         }));
        Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not get in from the question: does it reach the lines you provided above?

Comment: This is simply the code I am using to call the method. Creating the client and calling the method is all I am doing

Comment: The problem is likely to do with from where in the WPF app `SendReport` is being called, not in `SendReport` itself. Would you please edit your question to include the calling code?

Comment: Added the code as you requested

Comment: @Nensec and the problem actually is that `Execute` method is not actually fired?

Comment: And then, what happens if you step onto `Result = _client.SendErrorReport...` in the debugger?

Comment: Nothing. That is the problem. It just hangs and eventually VS spits out that it cannot debug the server. This does work in the console app. Can step into it just fine there and shows me the method call on the service

Comment: Oh, now I see, and that's really weird. I suspect now either a threading issue (all this Caliburn.Micro stuff looks really asynchronous), so I'd try putting the WCF code into a simple event handler. Also: does your WPF solution contain more than one project?

Comment: I know you say the config is identical but I would look at it again.  Test a method the returns a simple string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was indeed threading of some sort. While not happy with the implementation it now works.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new System.Action(() => { /* send report code */ }));
```